# how to check if an document is updated or inserted in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, upsert, mongodb-java

I'm just wondering if there's way to check if a given document is updated or inserted in MongoDB after a upsert operation in Java:

```
DBCollection col = getCollection();
// either this
col.findAndModify(query, null, null, false, contact, false, true);
// or this
WriteResult wr = col.update(query, contact, true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `WriteResult` will hold information regarding whether it was successful or not; if successful, the document will be there.

You could also do a simple `col.count(new BasicDBObject("_id",{id of your document}))` and check if the value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

1-> step : set the [profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler) using `> db.setProfilingLevel(2);` on the document target.
2-> run this query

```
db.system.profile.find({},{ts:1, op:1, ns:1}).sort({ts: -1}).forEach(printjson);
```

it will show you in the `op` attribute if the given document is updated or inserted and `ns` is the document name. `ts` when the query run.